# laravel 5.1 : Route issue

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have defined a route:

```
Route::get('admins', function () {
    return view('admins/index');
});
```

When i access `localhost/project/public/admins` then the project loads correctly but when i access `localhost/project/public/admins/` just by adding the `/` after `admins` then the `localhost/admins` loads which isn't there and throws `404`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this `Route::get('/admins'.....)`

it would be much better if you use prefixing/grouping to avoid this kind issue. here is the example

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin', 'middleware'=>'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('dashboard',                             ['as'=>'user-dashboard','uses'=>'Admin\UserController@dashboard']);

    # User Role Management
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'roles', 'middleware'=>'auth'],function(){
        Route::get('show',                            ['as'=>'roles-show', 'uses'=>'Admin\RolesController@index']);
        Route::get('data',                            ['as'=>'roles-data', 'uses'=>'Admin\RolesController@getData']);
        Route::get('create',                          ['as'=>'roles-create', 'uses'=>'Admin\RolesController@create']);
        Route::post('create',                         ['as'=>'roles-store', 'uses'=>'Admin\RolesController@store']);
        Route::get('edit/{id}',                       ['as'=>'roles-edit', 'uses'=>'Admin\RolesController@edit']);
        Route::post('edit/{id}',                      ['as'=>'roles-update', 'uses'=>'Admin\RolesController@update']);
        Route::post('delete',                         ['as'=>'roles-delete', 'uses'=>'Admin\RolesController@destroy']);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

to avoid this type of error you need to configure the .htaccess file. the .htaccess configurstion file is used to run the file without index.php or public.